# A correct pattern to use with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

I'm using the following angularjs project structure:

```
index.html
js/
-- angularjs
-- application.js
-- shared
-----SharedModule.js
-----LocalizeService.js
-----OtherSharedService.js
-- user
-----UserModule.js
-----LoginController.js
-----RegisterController.js
-----UserService.js
```

In other words I group files not by their type (e.g. services/controllers/directives), but by their logic purpose (e.g. user/shared/cart etc). I read this is the correct approach for large projects.

The main application.js file includes the modules like this:

```
angular.module('myApplication', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'sharedModule', 
    'userModule',
    'dahsboardModule',
])
```

Then, each module includes the related controllers/directives/services/whatever.

e.g. SharedModule.js

```
var sharedModule = angular.module('sharedModule',[]);

sharedModule.factory('Localize', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$window', LocalizeService]);

sharedModule.controller('someController',['$rootScope',SomeController]);
```

Then I implement the logic in each separate file.
My question is: what design pattern should I use to implement the logic of each separate service/controller?

I read this book: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/
and so far my beloved design pattern is 'Revealing module pattern' which is kinda omni-purpose design pattern. I used it many times in other projects (w/o angularjs).

But it seems I cannot use it with angularjs.

```
var LocalizeService = (function() {
})();
```

How can I pass all the stuff like $rootScope/$http to the module?

This is how it works for me now:

```
function LocalizeService($http,$rootScope,$window) {
   var localize = (function() {

      function publicFunction() {
            // do smth.
        }
      return {
          someFunction: publicFunction
      }
   })();
   return localize;
}
```

But I'm not sure if it is quite correct. Could you please kindly advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an use a `service` with a constructor instead of a `factory`:

```
var LocalizeService = (function() {
  function LocalizeService($http, $rootScope, $window) {

  }

  LocalizeService.prototype = {
    publicFunction: function() {

    }
  };

  LocalizeService.$inject = ['$http','$rootScope','$window'];

  return LocalizeService;
}());

sharedModule.service('Localize', LocalizeService);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error I got previously when I tried to use this pattern: MINERR_ASSET:22
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr].

Comment: Is your ngRoute dependency loaded? It's a separate script since Angular 1.2. Did you try following the link error in the console? It should take you to the documentation and provide some info on the error.

Comment: Yes, it is loaded and I've already read the description of the error following the link in the console. Please see code in the initial message. Should I load it somehow else? Am I doning smth. wrong?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/53AKdw2sSGTumtwarppc?p=options I get another error here. But anyway, I don't quite understand why I should use the Constructor pattern inside the Revealing module pattern?

Comment: Well, you're attempting to add the service before it exists... http://plnkr.co/edit/CAuPj5NZhmhrg0CvnvgD?p=preview

Comment: Shame on me. This was the origin of the issue. Thank you so much.